# Having 404 page not found issue

Tags: 404

The page doesn't appear without the index.php in the link. Please tell me how to fix it. E.g. localhost/sitename/index.php/category/. I want to remove index.php from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the following link, i believe it will be quite helpful for your situation.

[pages do not work without index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702708/magento-urls-other-than-home-page-do-not-work-without-index-php)